# my flutter app pauses when I add the ListView codes in the code and doesn't return direct crash message

Tags: flutter, listview, freeze

I am trying to build my first Flutter app.
I am using visual studio code for development

The following code is from my main.dart:

```
class mySamplePage3 extends StatelessWidget {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text(“Some title text here"),
    ),
  body: Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
    height: 400,
    width: 300,
    child: Column(
      children: [
      ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text("Back!", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
      ),
      
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// the code for the ListView

      ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        const SizedBox(height: 10,),

        const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          child: Divider(color: Colors.black, height: 30,),
        ),

          Card(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            elevation:20,
            color: Colors.purple[200],
            child: const ListTile(
              title: Text("Kadriye Macit"),
              subtitle: Text("Ankara"),
              trailing: Icon(Icons.call),
            ),
          ),
        ],
       )
      
///// the end of the ListView code
      ]
    )
  )
);
}
```

When I remove the ListView code block (which I put /// at the beginning and the end of the code), the code works without any problem. But when I keep this block, it hangs and visual studio core, and a red notification appears at CALL STACK window.

(I checked this ListView code but it works at the other debug-test web sites.)

After spending almost a day with dealing this problem, I asked my question here.

Thank you for any support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrape your listview in Expanded widget.
like this:

```
Expanded(child: ListView(
  children: [
    
  ],
))
```

Comment: both Yash's and this solution worked. But I could tick just one as the answer. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

You've enclosed the ListView within Columns, but the issue arises because the Columns have an infinite height, causing the ListView to occupy the entire available space.

**The solution to this problem is**:

You just need to set one property on the ListView to:

```
shrinkWrap: true,
```

By adding this property, the ListView will adapt its height to match the space required by its children, ensuring it doesn't take up unnecessary space.